# Parse JSON nested data from Requests POST response

Tags: python, json, django, python-requests

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) in which I have to parse a JSON returned from the POST request using `Requests` library.

> I googled a lot and tried too many solutions but nothing helped me, so
> don't mark this as duplicate, please!

Here's what I have tried:

```
def process_req(payload):
    try:
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        data = payload
        resp = requests.post(
            'http://<EXAMPLE_URL>',
            data=data,
            headers=headers
        )
        print('returned data: {}'.format(resp.content.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')))
        resp = resp.content.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
```

When I print the `resp` it provide the following JSON:

```
{
    "code": "00",
    "message": "Successful",
    "data": "{\"requestId\":\"0012602\",\"responseCode\":\"68\",\"responseDescription\":\"Invalid Institution Code\"}"
}
```

Now, I need to access the `data` field of that JSON, here what I tried:

```
resp['data']
```

But it returns an error as:

> string indices must be integers

Comment: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Answer (score 0):

You're retrieving the data as raw bytes by using `resp.content`.

Try `resp.json()` instead. This will decode the JSON into Python objects.

Comment: after how can I access the `data` field?